# Want to Capture Mule Project name and Configuration XML Name and Insert into a SQL table

Tags: mule

I want to Capture **"Mule Project name"** and **"Configuration XML Name"** and Insert into a SQL table.

I have highlighted them in yellow in screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ${app.name} property to get the application name at execution time. Note that it may not be the same that the project name, which is not available at execution time because it exist at design time in Studio.

You can't access the XML configuration name inside an application.